# in five years vs after five years

Tags: meaning, grammar

> - In five years he will come back.
> - After five years he will come back.

As a non-native speaker, these two sentences are grammatically right for me.  But semantically speaking, I think there is a slight difference. Could anyone explain the difference to me?

Comment: "In five years" implies five years from now. "After five years" can be five years from any time.

Comment: @Rathony I suspect that that's a rather demanding dupespot.